# LOAD DATA INFILE for inserting data into two tables concurrently?

Tags: mysql, csv, file-io, concurrency, load

I have a CSV file with over 100k records, and I need to insert certain fields into one table, and  the remaining fields into another table.

I know I can write two LOAD DATA INFILE queries one after other to get this, I tried that, and it works fine too. But I was wondering if it is possible to do the following:

1. Read a line from the csv file.
2. Take certain records, insert them in table A. Insert remaining into table B.
3. Read the next line. Repeat 2.

Is this possible at all? I know concurrency in MySQL is really gruelling on the system, but would like to know all my options.

Answer (score 1):

Row filter is not possible with `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

You can however create a small shell script using `grep` or `awk` that parses your file and only inserts the records that matches your criteria:

```
cat file.txt |
  awk '/\t.+/' |
    mysql -u your_username -pyour_password \
      -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/dev/stdin' \
          IGNORE INTO TABLE table_name         \
          COLUMNS TERMINATED BY '\t'          \
          LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'            \
          (col1, col2);" \
      database_name
```

Other better approach would be to load all the data in a temporary table and use this table to load the the data in original table by filter required data.